# What is the correct method to get all QLabels form UI in QList?

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel, qlist

```
QList<QLabel> labelList;

foreach (QLabel lbl, ui)
{
    labelList.append(lbl);
}
```

I wanted to add all QLabels in the `QList`, above code generates an error, please help

Comment: Please use more specific titles in your questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the list of pointers to the child widgets using `QList<T> QObject::findChildren ( const QString & name = QString() )`. If ui belongs to a `QMainWindow`, it could be done by:

```
QList<QLabel *> list = ui->centralWidget->findChildren<QLabel *>();
```

To find children of non-`QMainWindow` containers, such as `QDialog` or `QWidget`, use:

```
QList<QLabel *> list = this->findChildren<QLabel *>();
```

Now you can iterate through the list like:

```
foreach(QLabel *l, list)
{
  ...
}
```

Or, in C++11:

```
for(auto l : list)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you distinguish QMainWindow and QWidget here? `this->findChildren` should work fine for QMainWindow.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov You are right. I just wanted to use `ui` in some way.

Answer (score 3):

[findChildren](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChildren) should do exactly that: try

```
QList<QLabel*> labelList;  // note the pointer!

labelList = findChildren<QLabel*>();
```

to be executed in a QWidget derived object

Comment: `ui` normally is not a QObject and doesn't have `findChildren` method. You should just remove `ui->`.